# Match files on line beginning

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, textfiles

When giving parties, I record everything my guests eat.<sup>[1]</sup>

**Note**: I've inserted a few tabs to make everything readable.

`party1.txt`:

```
Bernhard    Apple
Jeremy      Cake
Liz         Cake
Daisy       Pear
```

`party2.txt`:

```
Liz         Cake
Bernhard    Pear
Jeremy      Cake
Susan       Orange
```

Now I want to see if the guests are predictable by comparing the files. I can use

```
cat party1.txt | sort > party1-sorted.txt
cat party2.txt | sort > party2-sorted.txt
```

But comparing by hand is slowly. Is there any bash opportunity to have a `pasteMatch` command, giving

```
Bernhard    Apple   Pear
Daisy       Pear    
Jeremy      Cake    Cake
Liz         Cake    Cake
Susan       Orange
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Not really, of course.

Comment: I was about you reply with "You need to get out more...", then I read [1].

Comment: Once they are sorted, try using the paste command to combine the different files into columns.  You may have to do some editing if not all people attended all parties.

Comment: When I use `paste`, the names get doubled as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is by using the [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) command.

The syntax will be :

```
join -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 party1-sorted.txt party2-sorted.txt
```

The default join field is the first, delimited by whitespace.
This command will however replace multiple blanks by one:

```
Bernhard Apple Pear
Daisy Pear
Jeremy Cake Cake
Liz Cake Cake
Susan Orange
```

A more sophisticated output format will require using awk or sed.

Comment: Small addition, with a little help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439906/6403504: The `-e HELLO` option gives the value `HELLO` for every party, the person had not been at (empty or unmatched field), but it only works when `-o auto` is specified as well.